# как избавить текст от <текст внутри> с помощью питона

Tags: python

Текст нужно избавить от <> и всего того, что внутри этих галочек(этот текст выделен на картинке)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Очень элементарный подход — пусть  ваш текст находится в переменной `text`:

```
result_list = []
delete_flag = False

for char in text:
    if char == "<":
        delete_flag = True
    if char == ">":
        delete_flag = False
    if not delete_flag and char != ">":
        result_list.append(char)

result = "".join(result_list)
```

---

**Проверка:**

Когда в переменной `text` будет текст из вашего вопроса

```
text = """<р>На станции Муслюмово Кунашакского микрорайона под
Челябинском горит птицефабрика, принадлежащая Уральской
мясной компании. Возгорание возникло в цеху по
выращиванию птицы, его площадь на момент прибытия
пожарных составила 800 квадратных метров.</р>, <р>Пожару
был присвоен повышенный номер сложности. Он был
локализован на площади 1200 квадратных метров, а затем
потушен, передает <а href="http://гіа.гu" target="_blank"><а
 href="http://гіа.гu" target="_blank">РИА Новости</а></а>.
Сведений о погибших и пострадавших нет.</р>, <р>Из здания
птицефабрики самостоятельно эвакуировался персонал — 8
человек.</р> <р>В тушении принимали участие 44 спасателя и
14 единиц спецтехники.</р></р>"""
```

то команда

```
print(result)
```

выводит на экран

```
На станции Муслюмово Кунашакского микрорайона под
Челябинском горит птицефабрика, принадлежащая Уральской
мясной компании. Возгорание возникло в цеху по
выращиванию птицы, его площадь на момент прибытия
пожарных составила 800 квадратных метров., Пожару
был присвоен повышенный номер сложности. Он был
локализован на площади 1200 квадратных метров, а затем
потушен, передает РИА Новости.
Сведений о погибших и пострадавших нет., Из здания
птицефабрики самостоятельно эвакуировался персонал — 8
человек. В тушении принимали участие 44 спасателя и
14 единиц спецтехники.
```

Answer (score 1):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) - лучшая библиотека для разбора кусков HTML

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>Some<b>bad<i>HTML")
soup.text()
```

Comment: Нет, без каких либо библиотек, просто с точки зрения работы с текстом на питоне

Comment: Так хочется сопоставлять скобки вручную?